Duplicates modules error during Qt Android release build
Apparently, I have added an external library in my project and post that, release build fails with the following error:
Type org.kde.necessitas.ministro.IMinistro is defined multiple times

I know that the external lib also used Qt for its development. Is there any way to remove this duplication?
The applications works fine in the debug mode.
The tools used are Qt 5.15.2, Android TargetSDK 34
